# How to copy multiple directories with spaces, in Linux shell

Tags: linux, shell, copy, wildcard

I have a directory of movies(they're in their own folders) and I only want to transfer some of them.

Why doesn't this work?

`movie*` represents a directory

```
cp -r {movie*, otherMovie*} "/var/media/store n go"

"cp: can't stat '{movie*,': No such file or directory"
"cp: can't stat 'otherMovie*}': No such file or directory"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't put a space after the comma, that prevents curly braces from being processed. So it's looking for files that match `{movie*,` (with a literal `{` at the beginning of the filename) and `othermovie*}` (with a `}` at the end of the filename).

```
cp -r {movie,otherMovie}* "/var/media/store n go"
```

This should work with spaces in the source names.

```
$ touch "Avengers Age of Ultron" "Die Hard A Good Day"
$ echo {"Avengers Age of"*,"Die Hard A Good"*}
Avengers Age of Ultron Die Hard A Good Day
```

Comment: Thanks, secondly, the wildcard doesn't seem to be working. I was hoping I would only have to type the start of the movie name instead of the whole thing. `{"Avengers Age of"*,"Die Hard A Good"*}` doesn't work. @Barmar

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're having, it works for me.